# Get hadoop counter value or custom message for killed job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working on a MapReduce job that needs to abort processing (in mapper) in case a certain number of records in the input files are malformed. To check the threshold, each time a record is detected a counter (org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Counter) is incremented by 1. If a mapper detects after incrementing by 1 that the threshold has been crossed it kills the job.

However I want to detect in the Driver that the failure was due the threshold being crossed. Since the job is killed the updated counter value is not available to the Driver, and there seems to be no way that a message or a status update can be passed from the mapper killing the job to the driver.

Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Take a look at this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654965/how-to-pass-variable-between-two-map-reduce-jobs

Comment: Counter doesn't seem like an option for me. I get the counter value in case the job passes (the counter reflects how many records failed in the passed job) but in case of the job failing or being killed I get no counter values in the driver.